# INSERT INTO using subquery is telling me an uninvolved field is the error?

Tags: mysql, subquery, default, alter

I'm not entirely sure how to explain what's happening but basically I'm trying to insert values into my table using a subquery and it's telling me that I'm getting an error because a field that is not involved in the query at all does not have a default value.

```
INSERT INTO customerPayment (customerOrderId) 
SELECT ID FROM customerOrder 
WHERE customerOrder.orderStateId = (
    SELECT ID 
    FROM orderState 
    WHERE orderState.state = "Payment Recieved"
);
```

> ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'total' doesn't have a default value

And then when I go into the table itself to try and set a default value for total, it then tells me I have an invalid default value for another unrelated field.

```
ALTER TABLE customerPayment ALTER total SET DEFAULT 0.0;
```

ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'paymentDate'

It may be relevant to note that 'paymentDate' currently has a default value of curdate().

Comment: I think you originally created the table with a different MySQL version or different server options, so it allowed the default value for `paymentDate`. But when you try to alter the table it re-validates the table definition, and now it won't allow that default for `paymentDate`.

Comment: That seems unlikely, I added the paymentDate column about 15 minutes before trying to run my insert query. I'm also performing these queries in the terminal and did not log out of my server in between them.

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE customerPayment` and tell us what the statement on `paymentDate`

Comment: `paymentDate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT (curdate())

Comment: total also has a constraint checking if its greater than 0.

Comment: Do you have any triggers in place?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the `total` column was created with `NOT NULL` condition but wasn't assigned with any default value. Something like this example:

```
 total DECIMAL(4,4) NOT NULL,
```

And it seems `CURDATE()` or `CURRENT_DATE()` can't be assigned as default value from my testing. Instead, the column datatype should be `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` then can only assign with default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` or `NOW()`. So, maybe the first step is to change the `paymentDate` datatype and default value like:

```
ALTER TABLE customerPayment MODIFY COLUMN `paymentDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW();
```

Then you can proceed with modifying the `total` column like:

```
ALTER TABLE customerPayment MODIFY COLUMN total DECIMAL(4,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0;
```

Then probably you can do your `INSERT` after that.

Here's a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4af3d11f90916469d8fbe61011b3fcab